# XML Import is getting fail in Excel 2007 due to invalid character

Tags: xml, excel

I am geting XML parse error while importing an xml file in excel 2007. Error is saying that "An Invalid character was found in the text content". Following invalid character (``) has been found in my xml file in some of the lines. My XML file declaration is follows ...`<?xml version="1.0"?>` and getting the same error if XML declaration is as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Please find the attachment for error and let me know how to overcome this error and let me know do i need to use any specific XML declaration at the begining to skip this error.

Comment: Try using an online validator - like [this one](http://validator.w3.org/) - to narrow down exactly what the problem is with the XML file

Comment: Unfortunately my edit removed it (possibly because the SO editor is smarter) but copy-pasting the character revealed that the offending one was `U+0014 DEVICE CONTROL FOUR`, which is a control character not permitted in XML. A Unicode fallback font is often helpful for identifying these characters.

Answer (score 0):

Open your xml file in the notepad++ . Then go to the line where excels says have illegal character. There will be some unicode character, you would need to delete that.